# Smarty: несколько тем оформления

Tags: php, smarty

Проблема такая. на сайте несколько тем оформления, причем они могут использоваться одновременно, допустим с разных доменов. у меня один движок, на пару доменов.
при заходе на первый сайт. все ок. отобразилось. захожу на второй. он оформляет его как надо, но контент содержание берет с 1го сайта (под содержанием я понимаю текстовое наполнение файла .tpl) с базы все берет как надо, база к смарти не имеет отношения.

Вопрос, как сделать чтобы шаблоны компилировались с какими то уникальными значениями? чтобы не пересекались скомпилированные файлы для разных сайтов.

я нашел выход - сделать для каждого сайта свою директорию компиляции, но это муторно. каждый раз добавлять новый шаблон + новую директорию...

может есть как то еще проще решение, чтобы сматри уже индификатор шаблона который используется встраивал в названия скомпилированный файлов??

Вон смарти в имена шаблонов при компиляции, добавляет какую то инфу:

```
%%2F^2F9^2F915824%%fotter.tpl
```

Можно сделать чтоб эта инфа была разная для разных тем? Или НЕВОЗМОЖНО? я сделал 2 разных папки для компиляции, но хотелось бы докопаться до сути!)

Comment: А как у вас шаблоны для разных сайтов расположены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в принципе так:

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir(array(
    'domain1.com' => 'templatesDir_1',
    'domain2.com' => 'templatesDir_2'
));

$domain_name = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

$smarty->display("file:[{$domain_name}]foo.tpl");
```